# “Self signed certificates” fail, but trust store not

Tags: tls, openssl

I'm using [paho.mqtt.c](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c) to connect in a "Self signed certificates" way to a MQTT broker.
I have 3 files I use:

```
- CAfile.pem (CERTIFICATE)
- PrivateKey.pem (PRIVATE KEY)
- Certifcate.pem.crt (CERTIFICATE)
```

When CAfile.pem contin the last certificate in the chain.

When connecting using the below I get a "Verify return code: 0 (ok)":

```
openssl s_client -connect 1234.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8883 
                 -cert Certifcate.pem.crt 
                 -key PrivateKey.pem 
                 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  #!!!!
```

When connecting using the below I get a "Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)":

```
openssl s_client -connect 1234.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8883 
                 -cert Certifcate.pem.crt 
                 -key PrivateKey.pem 
                 -CAfile CAfile.pem  #!!!!
```

I found out that the reason for the "Verify return code: 20..." is that [Starfield Class 2](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Heimdal/Heimdal-172.29/lib/hx509/data/sf-class2-root.pem.auto.html) (that are in my ca-certificates.crt) is missing.

When I concat [Starfield Class 2](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Heimdal/Heimdal-172.29/lib/hx509/data/sf-class2-root.pem.auto.html) to my 'CAfile.pem' it works.

Why the failure? How do I resolve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. You realized yourself that a  required intermediate certificate is not send  by the server and that adding it to the trust store helps. So you've already answered both why it fails and how it can be fixed. Also, I'm not sure how this relates to self-signed certificates since you are obviously not using a self-signed certificate for the server.

Comment: Your last comment is confusing for me. Your trust store is what you give with `-CAfile`. You say in your question that it works once you have added the missing certificate to the trust store which kind of implies that it wasn't in there before.

Comment: In -CAPath I pass the CAfile.pem, only one certificate, and it failes. When I change the -CAPath paramter to  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt it works. When I concat the  "Starfield Class 2" to "CAfile.pem" and use at in -CAPath it works.
I do not understand why.

Comment: This comment contradicts what you say in your question - where you claim that it fails with `ca-certificates.crt` and succeeds with `CAfile.pem`. Please fix your question to reflect the reality. Also, add what is exactly included in `CAfile.pem` since currently it is just the file you got without information about its contents.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that *Starfield Class 2 CA* is the root CA for the servers certificate. This root CA need to be included in the trust store. It is  not fully clear what exactly `CAfile.pem` contains but from your description of *"..contin the last certificate in the chain"* I assume it is the server certificate and not the root CA. Since the server certificate is not a CA certificate at all it will simply be ignored when given in the `-CAfile` parameter since this - as the name suggests - expects CA certificates.